# How to PARSE_JSON from Snowflake Field?

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like:

```
ID|FIELD1
1|[ { "list": [ {} ] } ]
2|[ { "list": [ { "item": "" } ] } ]
3|[ { "list": [ { "item": "Tag1" }, { "item": "Tag2" } ] } ]
```

And I want to get all the tags associated to this specific query such that I can just get a list:

```
Tag1,Tag2
```

I've tried

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON(FIELD1[0]['list'][0]['item']) FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE PARSE_JSON(FIELD1[0]['list'][0]) != '{}'
```

But I get

```
JSON: garbage in the numeric literal: 65-310 , pos 7
```

How can I properly unpack these values in SQL?

**UPDATE: Clumsy Solution**

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CODES,'\',\'') AS PROMO_CODES
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1[0]['list'][0]['item'] AS CODES FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE FIELD1[0]['list'][0] IS NOT NULL
AND FIELD1[0]['list'][0] != '{}'
AND FIELD1[0]['list'][0]['item'] != ''
)
```

Comment: What type is FIELD1? `PARSE_JSON` might not be needed, if the JSON has already been parsed

Answer (score 1):

As I see, the Clumsy Solution does not provide the correct result. It shows only Tag1. So here's my solution:

```
select LISTAGG( v.VALUE:item, ',' ) from MY_TABLE,
lateral flatten (parse_json(FIELD1[0]):list) v
WHERE v.VALUE:item <> '';
```

I would recommend to add DISTINCT to prevent duplicate tags in the output:

```
select LISTAGG( DISTINCT v.VALUE:item, ',' ) from MY_TABLE,
lateral flatten (parse_json(FIELD1[0]):list) v
WHERE v.VALUE:item <> '';
```

If there are more items in the FIELD1 array (ie 0,1,2), you may use this one:

```
select LISTAGG( DISTINCT v.VALUE:item, ',' ) from MY_TABLE,
lateral flatten(FIELD1) f,
lateral flatten (parse_json(f.VALUE):list) v
WHERE v.VALUE:item <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into below knowledge article, if this helps in your case:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extracting-JSON-using-LATERAL-FLATTEN